# How do I write a cross platform installer script?

Tags: windows, linux, installation, cross-platform

Instead of having a different download of a program for Windows and Linux, would it be possible to make the download be a cross-platform script/executable that can download the correct installer from an FTP server and start that? What language should I write it in? The only one I can think of would be Java, but I don't want to take the time to learn it. I can't write it in Python or BASH, because most Windows machines don't have these installed. How should I do this?

Comment: You could write a `.bat` script for Windows and a `.sh` script for Unix/Linux.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm doing this to try to avoid it. If I was going to do that, I would write an EXE for Windows and a Deb/RPM for Linux. I'm trying to make it one crossplatform download.

Comment: Platforms are different. We have to play by their rules and use the commands that they understand. Also, since its FTP how are you going to ensure that the windows machine FTP client acts the same way a Mac or Linux FTP client works. Just go with the Java option if you really dont want to write two scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-platform executable(like an exe or a.out or ELF) is out of question. An executable is never cross-platform when Windows is involved. The scripting languages(or JIT compiled) have to be brought in for this purpose. We are in a CHICKEN-AND-EGG paradox. You may have to detect the OS the downloader is using, using a Javascript script in your website page and decide on what is to be done next etc...

Although not exactly what you are looking for, below are some pointers.

The best tool I know of, for multi-platform installers, is [Flexera Software's InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm). That might be a bit costly. For free options I would look into options like:

PERL

PYTHON (but this is out of question as per your post, but look at the end of my post for more options for Python)

Although writing the installer in any of the above languages might mean a lot more work, they provide you unmatched flexibility and complete control.

Perl requires that you install Perl interpreter and modules on Windows. But this also seems to be out of question for you. So you may avoid the headache by looking into:

[PAR](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-1.005/lib/PAR.pm)

[pp](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.013/lib/pp.pm)

For Python go through:

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

[pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Comment: py2exe and pyinstaller doesn't make an installer, it simply makes a distributable folder